# SQLAlchemy: Many-to-Many dynamic loading on both sides

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, lazy-loading

Let's say I have the following:

```
association_table = Table('things_stuffs', Base.metadata,
    autoload=True,
    extend_existing=True)

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'things'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

class Stuff(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stuffs'
    __table_args__ = (
        {'autoload': True}
        )
    things = relationship(Thing,
                secondary=association_table,
                backref=backref("stuffs", uselist=False, lazy='dynamic'))
```

Now, if I want to get all the things from a Stuff instance I can do:

```
a_stuff_instance.things.filter().all()
```

And query it because of the `lazy="dynamic"` part. But the other side doesn't work. If I want to do

```
a_thing_instance.stuffs.filter().all()
```

I get `AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'filter'`. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `dynamic` to the other side as well:

```
things = relationship(Thing,
            secondary=association_table,
            lazy='dynamic', # *** @note: new parameter ***
            backref=backref("stuffs", uselist=False, lazy='dynamic'))
```

Comment: I won't get to test this out till Tuesday, but I'll check back in after I do! Thanks.